# Docker/Spring Boot/MongoDB: com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have the problem when I'm trying to run **docker-compose up** on my server. Everything works on my localhost.

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
  dictionary_app_prod_mongo:
    image: mongo
    container_name: springboot-mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - $HOME/data/springboot-mongo-data:/data/db
      - $HOME/data/springboot-mongo-bkp:/data/bkp
    restart: always
```

**application.properties:**

```
#Mongo configuration
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://springboot-mongo:27017/springmongo-demo
```

**Exception stacktrace:**

```
dictionary_app_prod          | 2019-11-23 11:28:41.789  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
dictionary_app_prod          | 2019-11-23 11:28:42.595  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
dictionary_app_prod          | 2019-11-23 11:28:42.736  INFO 1 --- [127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
dictionary_app_prod          |
dictionary_app_prod          | com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
dictionary_app_prod          |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:67) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:126) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod          | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
dictionary_app_prod          |  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
dictionary_app_prod          |  at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.8.2.jar!/:na]
dictionary_app_prod          |  ... 3 common frames omitted
```

**CMD on server: docker-compose ps**

```
dictionary_app_prod                         java -jar /app.jar            Up      0.0.0.0:8888->8082/tcp
dictionaryapp_dictionary_app_prod_mysql_1   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
springboot-mongo                            docker-entrypoint.sh mongod   Up      0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
```

Comment: If you try `docker-compose up -d` a second time, does it work?  A common problem here is the application starting up before the database is fully ready.

Comment: @DavidMaze application works normally but without mongodb connection. Moreover, I have **depends_on:** in my main application container (wanted to add full docker-compose, but stackoverflow doesn't allow me that)

Comment: `depends_on:` only causes Compose to start starting one container before it starts starting a second; Compose doesn't have any way to know the database is ready and accepting connections.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried to send a request to the mongo after starting the application and I noticed that I have the previsious version of the application. The problem fixed this command: **docker-compose build --no-cache** Thanks :)